# Multiple form screen when trying to set bounty

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounties

Trying to set a bounty on another users question, I got this.

- Browser :Google Chrome, Version 27.0.1453.110
- OS: Mac OS X ver 10.7.5

Details: 
No other problems,can set the bounty correctly ,The screen appeas twice that is all

[image: Fig 1]
[image: Fig 2]

Comment: Well, I see only one bounty so the bug is only in design. Not pretty, but not fatal.

Comment: Yeah no trouble ,But it is  wierd for a well managed site

Comment: Yep. Please add full browser version and OS you're using. :)

Comment: Included the details

Comment: Well, can't repro on Chrome 28 under Windows 7 hopefully the team can reproduce using your exact specs and fix it.

Comment: I can repro this on Firefox, but you have to *double-click* on "add bounty" and then click next. Please include such details next time.

Comment: @M.NightDemonbobby : I don't think i double clicked ,may be i did it, was in a hurry then.

Comment: I've tried a few different browser/OS combinations and I always get two forms after double clicking "start a bounty". The second image shows "bounty" has been highlighted, which probably means that you double clicked it as well.

Comment: oh ok :) good catch.

Comment: reproduced, looking into it

Answer (score 1):

Fixed as of build rev 2013.7.9.828